# Make treetableview uncollapseable, in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, treetableview

Is there a way to make a treetableview Un-collapsable, so that the treetable opens in expanded mode **setExpanded(true)** and can not be collapsed again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a listener on the tree item's expanded property and if it is set to false, set it back to true - that way the tree item will always be displayed expanded.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.*;

public class TreeViewSample extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("Inbox");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        IntStream.range(0, 6)
                .mapToObj(i -> new TreeItem<>("Message" + i))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(rootItem::getChildren));

        rootItem.expandedProperty().addListener(observable -> {
            if (!rootItem.isExpanded()) {
                rootItem.setExpanded(true);
            }
        });

        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>(rootItem);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(tree), 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide your root and set it expanded. It may solve your problem.

```
treeTable.setShowRoot(false);
root.setExpanded(true);
```

Comment: While this works for tree, it fails if the tree has nested inner elements.

Comment: If there is no value set to root, only the child has some values may it be nested or not, it will work

Comment: [A small example to show what I exactly meant earlier](https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/44202825a7c4b2b1cfa0). In the example, `Message 1` is still vulnerable to expansion and a user can un-collapse it.